# How are these two different definitions of the Poisson kernel on the n-torus related?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, poisson-summation-formula

I am interested in studying the Poisson kernel on the flat $n$-torus, $T^n$, and am trying to understand how to reconcile two separate definitions, both given in Grafakos's book, *Classial Fourier Analysis*. The two definitions are as follows:

\begin{align}
P_z(x) &=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}\frac{z^{-n}}{\left(1 + |\frac{x+m}{z}|^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\\
&= \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \exp(-2\pi|m|z)\exp(2\pi i m\cdot x), \hspace{1em} (1)
\end{align}

which comes from periodizing the Poisson kernel on upper-half space (*Section 4.3, Multipliers, Transference and A.E. Convergence; proof of theorem 4.3.4*), and

\begin{align}
P_{r_1, \dots, r_n}(x) &= \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1 - r_{k}^2}{1 - 2r_{k}\cos(x_k) + r_{k}^2}\right)\\
&= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^n} r_{1}^{|m_1|}r_{2}^{|m_2|}\cdots r_{n}^{|m_n|} \exp(2\pi i m\cdot x), \hspace{1em} (2)
\end{align}

which is given by a product of $n$ 1D Poisson kernels on the unit disc (*Section 3.1, Fourier Coefficients; exercise 3.1.7*).

If we let $r_{1} = r_{2} = \cdots = r_{n} = r$ in case (2) then we may write:

\begin{align}
P_{r}(x) &= \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(x_k) + r^2}\right)\\
&= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^n} r^{|m_1|+|m_2| + \cdots + |m_n|}\exp(2\pi i m\cdot x). \hspace{1em} (3)
\end{align}

Letting $r = \exp(-2\pi z),$ (3) becomes

\begin{align}
P_{r}(x) &= \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(x_k) + r^2}\right)\\
&= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \exp(-2\pi(|m_1|+|m_2| + \cdots + |m_n|)z)\exp(2\pi i m\cdot x). \hspace{1em} (4)
\end{align}

Now, (1) and (4) are very similar, the difference being the metric on the lattice points $m$. That is, if we impose the taxicab metric on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ so that $|m| = |m_1| + |m_2| + \cdots |m_n|$ then these two definitions become equivalent.

I am hoping for insight into some fundamental (topological? geometric?) distinction between these two definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have at least a partial answer to this question. In Stein and Weiss's book *Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces* in Chapter III.3 Tubes over Cones, they construct the Cauchy kernel using the cone
$$
\Gamma = \{(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid y_k > 0 \; \text{ for } k = 1, \dots, n\}
$$
and the tube $T_{\Gamma}$
where $z = (z_1, \dots, z_n) \in T_{\Gamma}$ if for each $k$ we have $z_k = x_k + i y_k$ and $(y_1, \dots, y_k) \in \Gamma$. The Cauchy kernel associated to $T_{\Gamma}$ is then given by
\begin{align*}
K(z) &= \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \cdots \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{2\pi i(z_1 t_1 + z_2t_2 + \cdots + z_n t_n)}\; dt_1\;dt_2\;\cdots\;dt_n\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{-1}{2\pi i z_{k}}.
\end{align*}

The Poisson kernel can be computed by
$$
P(x, y) = \frac{|K(z)|^2}{K(2iy)} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y_{k}}{x_k^2 + y_k^2}
$$
where $y_k > 0$ for each $k = 1, \dots, n$.
The multidimensional Fourier transform of this function in the $x_k$ coordinates is:
\begin{align*}
\hat{P}_{y}(\xi) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y_{k}}{x_k^2 + y_k^2}e^{-2\pi i x_k \xi_k}\right)\;dx_1 \; dx_2 \cdots dx_{n}\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y_{k}}{x_k^2 + y_k^2}e^{-2\pi i x_k \xi_1}\right)\; dx_k\\
&= e^{-2\pi(|\xi_1|y_1 + |\xi_2|y_2 + \cdots |\xi_n| y_n)}.
\end{align*}
So, again using Poisson summation, we have (at least formally) the identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y_{k}}{(x_k - m_k)^2 + y_k^2} &= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-2\pi(|m_1|y_1 + |m_2|y_2 + \cdots |m_n| y_n)} e^{2\pi i m \cdot x}\\
&= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} r_1^{|m_1}| r_2^{|m_2|} \cdots r_n^{|m_n|} e^{2\pi m \cdot x}\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1 - r_k^2}{1 - 2r_k \cos(x_k) + r_k^2},
\end{align*}
where $r_k = e^{-2\pi y_k}$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$. If we like, we can consider $y_1 = y_2 = \cdots y_k$ to unify the different radii. In any case, if we consider the definition of the $n$-Torus as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ given by:
$$
T^n = \left\{(e^{2\pi i x_1}, e^{2\pi i x_2}, \dots, e^{2\pi i x_n}) \mid x_k \in [0,1] \text{ for } k = 1, \dots, n\right\},
$$
we can consider the related subset
$$
\left\{(e^{2\pi i (x_1 + iy_1)}, e^{2\pi i (x_2 + iy_2)}, \dots, e^{2\pi i (x_n + iy_n}) \mid x_k \in [0,1], y_k > 0 \text{ for } k = 1, \dots, n\right\} = \left\{(r_1 e^{2\pi i x_1}, r_2 e^{2\pi i x_2}, \dots, r_n e^{2\pi i x_n}) \mid x_k, r_k \in [0,1] \text{ for } k = 1, \dots, n\right\}
$$ on which to consider this Poisson kernel. I am still unsure of what to make of this geometrically, but it at least further justifies the validity of the product of the 1D Poisson kernels on the unit disk as a valid Poisson kernel in some setting, and provides some more distinction between the two definitions.